# No me carga el archivo js vinculado desde el functions.php

Tags: php, javascript, bootstrap, wordpress

estoy haciendo una web en wordpress, quiero incluir algunas funcionalidades con JS, por lo que he creado un archivo llamado mi_script.js en el directorio js/mi_script.js

He creado un simple boton con un alert para ver si funciona, pero me da error en la consola de que no reconoce la funcion.

Adjunto el codigo del functions a ver si me podeis decir donde estoy cometiendo el error.

```html
function pyrans_styles() {
    // registrar estilos
    wp_register_style('normalize', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/normalize.css', array(),'5.0');
    wp_register_style('style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array('normalize'),'1.0');

    //llamar a los estilos
    wp_enqueue_style('normalize');
    wp_enqueue_style('style');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css");
    wp_enqueue_style( 'fontawesome', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome.min.css' );

    wp_enqueue_style('Montserrat', "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,700,800&display=swap");
    wp_enqueue_style('Open_Sans', "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700&display=swap");


    

    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrapjs', "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js", array('jquery'), '3.3.6', true );

    //registrar js, el TRUE sirve para q cargue el archivo en el footer
    wp_register_script('scripts', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/scripts.js', array(),'1.1.0', true);

    //llamar al js
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    // El jquery ya viene instalador en WP, por lo que solo tenemos que hacer la llamada.
    wp_enqueue_script('mi_script');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pyrans_styles' );
```

```html
$ = jQuery.noConflict();

$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $('.mobile-menu a').on('click', function(){
        $('nav.menu-sitio').toggle('slow');
    } );
    
    var breakpoint = 768;
    $(window).resize(function(){
//        console.log( $(document).width() ) 
//        para ver el tamaño de la pantalla en la consola
        if($(document).width() >= breakpoint){
             $('nav.menu-sitio').show();
        }else{
            $('nav.menu-sitio').hide();
        }
    } );
    
    function myFunction() {
        alert("I am an alert box!");
      }
    
    
});
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

No sé si estoy cometiendo algun error al insertar la libreria de bootstrap, ya que cada versión reciente cambia, agrederia que me dijeseis si lo estoy haciendo bien o mal. Espero vuestra respuesta ! Gracias

Comment: No queda claro en tu pregunta pero tenés que estar trabajando con child theme sino cualquier cambio que hagas será sobreescrito cuando actualices el theme. Luego el lugar para el archivo js debería estar dentro del child theme. Recién a partir de ahi tiene sentido ver lo que tenés mal en el uso del `wp_enqueue_script('mi_script');`

Comment: Ahí te dejé una respuesta, y ojo porque bootrstap tiene problemas con el dashboard de wp (o al menos solía tenerlos).

Comment: Perdon, he eliminado el comentario anterior porque me he equivocado. No estoy usando un tema child, estoy desarrollando un tema nuevo.

Comment: `<button onclick="myFunction()">` es una lotería si no sabes si el script que define `myFunction()` se carga antes o después de que el elemento `button` exista, lo mas aconsejable en estos casos es asignarle una clase o id al boton y luego usar `jQuery(document).ready(function() {` para asignarle el evento `onclick` al botón por `class` o `ID` una vez que se cargó todo el html y el elemento existe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El script mi_script.js tiene que estar dentro del theme / childtheme.

```
<directorio de wp>/wp-content/themes/<tu theme>/js/mi_script.js
```

Luego encolar el script con las dependencias de `bootstrap` y `jquery` (me pareció entdender que tu script depende de estos dos, sino podés dejar el array vacío.)

Si estás haciendo un theme:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'mi_script', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/mi_script.js', array('bootstrapjs','jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
```

Si estás haciendo un child theme entonces en lugar de `get_template_directory_uri()`, tenes que usar `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`

Para revisar si el script está siendo incluido, revisá antes del tag de cierre del `body` los diferentes tags de `script`. uno de ellos debería tener el href de mi_script.js.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resuelto en encolamiento del script, hay que corregir algunas cosas del `script.js`:

Wordpress ya tiene el `noconflict` activado para `jQuery`, es decir que el "`$`" no funciona y hay que usarlo con `jQuery` directamente.

Para poder usar la variable "`$`" dentro del `ready()` de `jQuery` se pasa como parámetro de la función.

En cuanto al botón cuando se selecciona, se llama a `myFunction()`, pero esta función está definida adentro de la función `ready()` por lo que no está visible fuera de ese contexto.

La solución es enlazar con el evento click del botón dentro del ambito donde la fución está visible, osea dentro del `ready()`;

Para hacer eso, le agrego una clase al botón que luego puedo usar para encontrar el botón con `jQuery`.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {

  function myFunction(){
     alert("I am an alert box!");
  }

  $("button.alert-button").click(function(){
        myFunction();
  });

});
```

Y el html:

```
<button class="alert-button">Try it</button>
```

Comment: He insertado el codigo wp_enqueue_script( 'mi_script', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/mi_script.js', array('bootstrapjs','jquery'), '1.0.0', true ); Pero sigue sin reconocerme js. Me da el siguiente error:
ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined. 
Hace falta registrarlo antes de hacer el wp_enqueue_script ?

Comment: Juan he añadido el script para que lo veas, no es nada del otro mundo. He hecho una prueba de colocar el <script> junto al codigo tal que asi sin archivo adjunto: 
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        alert("I am an alert box!");
      }
</script>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
Así funciona. Por lo que está claro que falla es la vinculacion que no sé commo solucionar.

Comment: He inspeccionado el boton, y lo unico que veo logico es que no aparece el contenido de la funcion, aparece vacia. :S He añadido una imagen para que puedas verlo.

Comment: Sí, aparece el script "mi_script" antes del cierre del body. Sigo sin saber porque no funciona :/

Comment: he añadido un boton, lo he cogido de esta web: https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_alert